# Why do these macros not evaluate to the same so that \ifx is true?

Tags: macros, conditionals, plain-tex

I have a document with paragraphs that were transcribed from an interview. Each of the paragraphs is from one author, alternating. Starting with "Author 1" I want to add the author name in front of each paragraph:

```latex
\let\plainpar\par
\def\fs{Author 1}
\def\mw{Author 2}
\def\author{\mw}
\def\par{%
  \wlog{\author==\fs?}
  \ifx\author\fs%
    \wlog{=> setting \mw}
    \def\author{\mw}
  \else
    \wlog{=> setting \fs}
    \def\author{\fs}
  \fi
  \plainpar\author: %
}

Par1

Par2

Par3
\let\par\plainpar
\end
```

My idea was to redefine `\par` in terms of changing the author and then printing it before the paragraph.
However, the outpupt only contains "Author 1:" in front of each paragraph.
Inspecting the log, I find this:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=tex 2022.7.15)  4 FEB 2023 16:28
**stunde_short.tex
(./stunde_short.tex
Author 2==Author 1?
=> setting Author 1
Author 1==Author 1?
=> setting Author 1
Author 1==Author 1?
=> setting Author 1
 [1] )
Output written on stunde_short.dvi (1 page, 292 bytes).
```

It seems that it works the first time and redefines `\author` correctly.
On subsequent checks `\ifx`, however, evaluates to false, even though `\author` and `\fs` seem to evaluate to the same.

I would expect to get the output

```
Author 1: Par1
Author 2: Par2
Author 1: Par3
```

What am I missing regarding `\ifx`?

Comment: you need `\expandafter\ifx\author\fs`.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you; why is `\expandafter` needed though? shouldn't `\ifx` be "True if two macros expands to the same, or [...]"? [source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Conditionals)

Comment: that's an imprecise description (and omits the important difference between once-expansion and full-expansion) -- for references on TeX primitives there are TeXbook/TeX by topic -- there are some examples in page 142 of TeX by topic, you can see \a is different from \d there.

Comment: I am not aware of what a description environment is. I thought it easiest to run through all paragraphs and just label them alternatingly, and for that I used the stuff from `tex` that I know/already learned but if there is a better solution I'd be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: Never mind.  The key here is **alternating**.  I thought you were constructing a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\ifx` conditional examines the two following tokens without expanding them. It then returns true provided

- both tokens are character tokens or control sequences `\let` to a character and they're the same (with respect to both character code and category code), or
- both tokens are control sequences and are the same primitive (maybe with different names), or
- both tokens are macros and have the same status with respect to `\outer`, and `\long` (and `\protected` when e-TeX is used), the same parameter text and the same replacement text.

You're confused by the output of `\wlog` that does *full expansion*. Sometimes the last condition is reported as “having the same expansion”, but this is very imprecise, because only the replacement text is compared, without further expansion.

Your macros `\author` and `\ws` don't satisfy the last condition, because the first level expansion of `\author` is `\fs` and the first level expansion of `\fs` is `Author 1`.

I'd use `\everypar` instead of redefining `\par`.

```
\def\interviewer{Interviewer}
\def\interviewee{Interviewee}

\newif\ifinterviewer
\interviewertrue
\def\alternatespeakers{%
  \ifinterviewer
    \interviewer:~
    \interviewerfalse
  \else
    \interviewee:~
    \interviewertrue
  \fi
}

\begingroup

\everypar{\alternatespeakers}

Par 1

Par 2

Par 3

Par 4

\endgroup

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As already said in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673986/118714), `\ifx` compares what is called the meaning of subsequent two tokens. I.e., the gathering and comparison of the two subsequent tokens is without evaluation/expansion.

E.g., after `\def\author{\fs}` the command `\show\author` reveals on the console:

```
> \author=macro:
->\fs .
```

E.g., after `\def\author{\mw}` the command `\show\author` reveals on the console:

```
> \author=macro:
->\mw .
```

E.g., after `\def\fs{Author 1}` the command `\show\fs` reveals on the console:

```
> \fs=macro:
->Author 1.
```

E.g., after `\def\mw{Author 2}` the command `\show\mw` reveals on the console:

```
> \mw=macro:
->Author 2.
```

As you can see, both the meaning of `\fs` and the meaning of `\mw` never equals the meaning of `\author`, therefore the `\ifx`-comparison of `\author` and `\fs` never yields the "true"-branch/always yields the "false"-branch.

(Be aware that `\show` and `\meaning` do not reveal every piece of information that might belong to the meaning of a token.

For example with

```
> \mw=macro:
->Author 2.
```

you don't know about the categories which the character-tokens `A`. `u`, `t`, `h`, `o`, `r`, *⟨space⟩*, `2` have.)

---

**You can fix things by using `\let` for assigning `\author` the meaning of `\fs`/`\mw`:**

*(If you have defined a control-sequence `\bar`, then the effect of `\let\foo=\bar` is that henceforth `\foo` has the meaning which `\bar` had at the time of performing the `\let`-assignment. `\foo` can be considered a copy with different "shape" of what `\bar` is at the time of performing the `\let`-assignment.)*

E.g., after `\def\fs{Author 1}` and `\let\author = \fs`
`\show\fs` reveals on the console:

```
> \fs=macro:
->Author 1.
```

`\show\author` reveals on the console:

```
> \author=macro:
->Author 1.
```

, i.e., `\fs` and `\author` have the same meaning.

E.g., after `\def\mw{Author 2}` and `\let\author = \mw`
`\show\mw` reveals on the console:

```
> \mw=macro:
->Author 2.
```

`\show\author` reveals on the console:

```
> \author=macro:
->Author 2.
```

, i.e., `\mw` and `\author` have the same meaning.

---

Thus in your scenario you can do:

```tex
\let\plainpar\par
\def\fs{Author 1}%
\def\mw{Author 2}%
% initialize \author:
\let\author=\mw
\def\par{%
  \wlog{\author==\fs?}%
  \ifx\author\fs
    \wlog{=> setting \mw}%
    \let\author=\mw
  \else
    \wlog{=> setting \fs}%
    \let\author=\fs
  \fi
  \plainpar\author: %
}%

Par1

Par2

Par3
\let\par\plainpar
\end
```

[image]

But `\let` has its caveats. E.g., often a command internally consists of several macros which form a "mechanism" (or "function" in expl3-jargon). The package [letltxmacro](https://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) takes care of most common of the like situations which one might encounter without being aware when using LaTeX.

---

Via `\csname..\endcsname` you can have TeX create control sequence tokens whose names also contain non-letters like digits or spaces.

Thus `\csname..\endcsname` can easily be used for mapping the value of a `\count`-register to a specific control sequence token/to a specific control sequence token's current expansion.

E.g., if you like you can use a `\count`-register and have TeX define/via `\everypar` call the corresponding participant-macro via `\csname..\endcsname`:

```tex
%------------------------------------------------------------
% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
%............................................................
\long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
\long\def\InnerCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}%
\long\def\Exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
%------------------------------------------------------------
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 1}{First Author}%
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 2}{Second Author}%
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 3}{Third Author}%
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 4}{Fourth Author}%
\def\participantMAX{4}%
\newcount\participantCNT
\participantCNT=0 %
\def\nextparticipant{%
  \global\ifnum\participantCNT<\participantMAX\advance\fi\participantCNT 1 %
  \CsNameToCsToken{participant \the\participantCNT}: %
}%
\def\setparticipant#1{%
  \global\participantCNT=#1\relax
  \global\advance\participantCNT by-1 %
  \ignorespaces
}%


\begingroup
\everypar{\nextparticipant}%

Par1

Par2

Par3

Par4

Par5

Par6

Par7

Par8

\setparticipant{3}
Par9 (Here participant was changed via {\tt\string\setparticipant})
\endgroup

\bye
```

[image]

Using `\numexpr` from ε-TeX-extensions you can do without wasting a `\count`-register:

```tex
%------------------------------------------------------------
% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
%............................................................
\long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
\long\def\InnerCsNameToCsToken#1#2{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{#1}%
}%
\long\def\Exchange#1#2{#2#1}%
%------------------------------------------------------------
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 1}{First Author}%
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 2}{Second Author}%
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 3}{Third Author}%
\CsNameToCsToken\def{participant 4}{Fourth Author}%
\def\participantMAX{4}%
\gdef\participantCNT{0}%
\def\nextparticipant{%
  \xdef\participantCNT{%
    \the\numexpr
      % somehow get a space-token behind \participantMAX
      \ifnum\participantCNT<\participantMAX\Exchange{}{} \participantCNT+\fi
      1%
    \relax
  }%
  \CsNameToCsToken{participant \participantCNT}: %
}%
\def\setparticipant#1{%
  \xdef\participantCNT{\the\numexpr(#1)-1\relax}%
  \ignorespaces
}%


\begingroup
\everypar{\nextparticipant}%

Par1

Par2

Par3

Par4

Par5

Par6

Par7

Par8

\setparticipant{3}
Par9 (Here participant was changed via {\tt\string\setparticipant})
\endgroup

\bye
```

[image]

---

However be aware that there are some caveats with delaying/timing the expansion of `\csname..\endcsname`-expressions.

For example, if `\csname..\endcsname` ends up unexpanded within a so-called moving argument which is also used by the output-routine for creating page-headers with uppercase-letters, the routine for uppercasing might turn `\csname foobar\endcsname` into `\csname FOOBAR\endcsname` so that instead of the control-word-token `\foobar` there will be the control-word-token `\FOOBAR`, which in turn might not trigger TeX into doing what you want TeX to do. ;-)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for this comprehensive explanation and the examples to do this differently! I'm still not through the TeXbook, but having more and more (in this case concrete) examples definitely helps learning plain TeX and its' variants/extensions